# mb_convert_case() treats non-breaking space as part of the word

Tags: php, capitalization

I need to convert series of comma-separated words to Title Case. Problems happen when I'm trying to convert strings like these:

```
foobar, 2&nbsp;foo
3&nbsp;bar
```

When I use mb_convert_case($foobar, MB_CASE_TITLE) on these, they look like this:

```
Foobar, 2 foo
3 bar
```

instead of:

```
Foobar, 2 Foo
3 Bar
```

Is there a way to title-case these strings these while preserving the non-breaking space?

Comment: That's not surprising.  Why do you have an HTML entity in your PHP string?  Only convert to HTML entities when you're outputting them to the view.

Comment: [Try this](https://3v4l.org/8G04W): `echo mb_convert_case(html_entity_decode($foobar), MB_CASE_TITLE);`

Comment: @Devon, I have this in a function that prepares the output.

Comment: @AntonsKijaņica that doesn't matter.  You should be calling mb_convert_case before you convert to entities then.

Comment: @Devon, sure, I might be doing this wrong. I am not very familiar with the MVC concept, and I am not ready to adopt it just yet. I have a need for a non-breaking space in a very specific place -- i.e. in place of the space in "\d foobar". Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `&nbsp;` with a space, and then capitalize all words, like this:

```
$string = 'foobar, 2&nbsp;foo 3&nbsp;bar';
$string = preg_replace("/\s|&nbsp;/",' ', $string);
$output = ucwords($string);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/mU3WS)